# How to sort algorithms with processing (beginner)?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, processing

Thanks for your time!

So I am trying to learn how to sort algorithms and watched a couple tutorial videos. Right now I am trying to declare an int variable "num" for values let's say 10-300. I am trying to create an int array "nums" that has "num" elements. Using random () to generate numbers from 1-1000 and put them in "nums". I wanted to implement 3 functions bubbleSort(), selectionSort(), and inserstionSort() that do bubble sort, selection sort, and insertion sort. After that I want to declare another int array "numt", copy all elements of nums array to numt and perform sorting in numt. After sorting completes, print the results with each number separated by a blank space. Hopefully this makes sense!

Comment: You can't just ask us to do it.. We need the code that you tried (if you did).

Comment: sorry it was my first time using this site. i apologize for being an idiot! will come back with the code.

Comment: You're not an idiot. There's always a first time.

Comment: That's why the site prompts you to read the help section and understand what is acceptable here before asking the first time.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow. It's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions. Stack Overflow is more designed for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions.

That being said, I'll try to help you in a general sense:

> I am trying to learn how to sort algorithms

Small nitpick: you aren't sorting algorithms, you're **using** sorting algorithms to sort an array.

> Right now I am trying to declare an int variable "num" for values let's say 10-300.

I'm not exactly sure why you need this variable, but you could do it pretty easily:

```
int num = 100; //assigns 100 to num
int num = int(random(10, 300)); //assigns random number between 10 and 300 to num
```

> I am trying to create an int array "nums" that has "num" elements.

Just use the standard array syntax, passing in `num` as the size:

```
int[] nums = new int[num];
```

> Using random () to generate numbers from 1-1000 and put them in "nums".

For this you'd use a `for` loop to assign each index of the array a random value.

> After that I want to declare another int array "numt", copy all elements of nums array to numt and perform sorting in numt.

You can use another `for` loop to copy values from one array into another.

> I wanted to implement 3 functions bubbleSort(), selectionSort(), and inserstionSort()

Start with something much simpler first, like a function that simply prints out the values in the array. From there you can implement more complicated logic.

> do bubble sort, selection sort, and insertion sort

You can look these algorithms up on the internet. Wikipedia has entries on all of them.

But you might want to take a step back and ask yourself: how would you do this by yourself, without reading about any of these algorithms? If somebody handed you a bunch of index cards and asked you to put them in order, how would you do it? Try implementing that before you implement any other algorithms.

Also, you might want to ask yourself why you're doing this. Is it for homework? Or do you just need to sort an array? If so you might just use a built-in sorting function to do the work for you.